# Idea of Lookup shaders

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

Here is an example of a shader:

```
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;


varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate2; // TODO: This is not used

 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2; // lookup texture

 void main()
 {
     lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);

 mediump float blueColor = textureColor.b * 63.0;

 mediump vec2 quad1;
 quad1.y = floor(floor(blueColor) / 8.0);
 quad1.x = floor(blueColor) - (quad1.y * 8.0);

 mediump vec2 quad2;
 quad2.y = floor(ceil(blueColor) / 8.0);
 quad2.x = ceil(blueColor) - (quad2.y * 8.0);

 highp vec2 texPos1;
 texPos1.x = (quad1.x * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.r);
 texPos1.y = (quad1.y * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.g);

 highp vec2 texPos2;
 texPos2.x = (quad2.x * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.r);
 texPos2.y = (quad2.y * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.g);

 lowp vec4 newColor1 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, texPos1);
 lowp vec4 newColor2 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, texPos2);

 lowp vec4 newColor = mix(newColor1, newColor2, fract(blueColor));
 gl_FragColor = vec4(newColor.rgb, textureColor.w);
```

}

This shader adds effect of blue edges around the image. It uses additional texture for calculation. Here is the texture:
https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Resources/lookup.png
Can someone explain purpose of this texture. In code this texture is stored in inputImageTexture2 variable. What is an idea and algorithm ?
For example if a want to get red edges instead of blue how i need to modify the input texture.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try just adding the blue color to the red color channel instead?

Answer (score 2):

This particular filter was written by Lev Zelensky, and he describes its configuration on [his blog](http://liovch.blogspot.com/2012/07/add-instagram-like-effects-to-your-ios.html).

Basically, you start with the base RGB lookup table, take it into Photoshop and apply the color effect you want to reproduce, then take the resulting image and use that as the lookup table for this filter. For each RGB value in the image, the closest match in that table will be found and used instead of the original color.

As for why you're seeing a blue tinge to the outside of your image, make sure you're generating and saving your lookup table correctly and that you're adding it in the right input slot for the filter.